# Which immigration and customs checkpoints should one use when walking across the border from Singapore to Malaysia via the Johor–Singapore Causeway?

Tags: borders, singapore, malaysia, walking

I read on the [Wikipedia page on the Sultan Iskandar Building](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sultan_Iskandar_Building&oldid=1176222723)  ([Google Maps](https://maps.app.goo.gl/T7FvoiwjaQ2pzVt18)) that is used to enter Malaysia from Singapore via the [Johor–Singapore Causeway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johor%E2%80%93Singapore_Causeway) ([Google Maps](https://maps.app.goo.gl/c5yoVAT317KqxujG7)) (formatting is mine):

> - The immigration checkpoint has different checkpoints for bus passengers, bus drivers, lorries, motorcycles and cars. [...]
> - At the customs checkpoint, 36 counters are designated for cars (20 for those arriving in Malaysia and 16 for those leaving the country) and 25 for motorcycles (17 for arrivals and 8 for departures).

Which immigration and customs checkpoints should one use when walking across the border from Singapore to Malaysia via the Johor–Singapore Causeway?

Comment: You should use the checkpoints the signs point you to. You don't have a choice in the matter.

Comment: @GregHewgill I don't know whether there are some clear signs for pedestrians. The causeway doesn't even have a sidewalk on some significant sections. E.g., maybe there are no signs and pedestrians can choose which checkpoint to walk through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which immigration and customs checkpoints should one use when walking across the border from Singapore to Malaysia via the Johor–Singapore Causeway?

Checkpoints for bus passengers. Same on the way back when entering Singapore from Malaysia.